# Move MVC application in VS2008 to windows azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure

I am new to Azure.I have MVC application build in VS 2008. It does not uses any database. How can I migrate the application to windows azure.

1. Which SDK and tool kit i should use.
2. Do i need to upgrade my app to 2010 before migrating
3. Is there any built in support for MVC
4. What role I should use

Thanks 
Ank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Which SDK and tool kit i should use.

1.4 is the latest [download link](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=7a1089b6-4050-4307-86c4-9dadaa5ed018)

> Do i need to upgrade my app to 2010 before migrating

yes, SDK 1.4 does not support 2008

> Is there any built in support for MVC

yes you will find a ASP.NET MVC 2 WebRole template`

> What role I should use

this depends, try starting with Extra Small

Comment: Thanks for the reply,   But there are previous relelease version 1.2(June). Can't I use it then I don't have to migrate my apps

Comment: @Ankush you can use 1.2, but you won't be able to use new features in Azure for e.g. Extra Small VM, debugging capabilities, multiple web roles etc.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Azure hosts various roles, one of which is a WebRole. You can easily place an MVC project into this role for hosting on Azure.

Firstly, you will need to upgrade to VS2010 as I believe the latest SDK (Version 1.4) only supports VS2010. Download that from here http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=7a1089b6-4050-4307-86c4-9dadaa5ed018&displaylang=en

Once you have it installed, you create a Cloud project in VS. You then add your existing MVC projects to this solution. You then add a web role to the Cloud project you created and select your MVC project as the target.

There are a few things extra you need, such as setting copy-local on some referenced assemblies.

Here is an excellent post on the subject: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jnak/archive/2008/10/28/asp-net-mvc-projects-running-on-windows-azure.aspx

Comment: But there are previous relelease version 1.2(June) which support VS 2008. Can't I use it then I don't have to migrate my apps

Comment: Yes, that's possible I suppose.